# add/remove class based on url or filename using php

Tags: php

I am trying to add a class to a div tag if on a specific page, for example if on index.php then a class needs to be removed from the div tag but if on computer-pc-repair.php a class needs to be added to a div tag

I tried the following but it just adds the bg-gray class if on index.php or not

`<div class="header-top-bar-info <?php echo ($_GET['page'] == 'computer-pc-repair.php')? '' : 'bg-gray'; ?> border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">`

The above outputs `<div class="header-top-bar-info bg-gray border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">`

I have found a way to do it using the following code which seems to be working

```php
<?php 

           if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index') == false) {
               echo '<div class="header-top-bar-info bg-gray d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="top-bar-wrap">
                            <div class="top-bar-left">
                                <div class="top-bar-text"><a href="#" class="font-medium display-inline">Now Hiring:</a> Are you a driven and motivated 1st Line IT Support Engineer?</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-bar-right">
                                <ul class="top-bar-info">
                                    <li class="info-item">
                                        <a href="tel:01228899900" class="info-link">
                                            <i class="info-icon fa fa-phone"></i>
                                            <span class="info-text"><strong>0122 8899900</strong></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="info-item">
                                        <i class="info-icon fa fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                                        <span class="info-text">58 Howard Street #2 San Francisco</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';}

    ?>
```

```php
<?php 

           if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index') == true) {
               echo '<div class="header-top-bar-info border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="top-bar-wrap">
                            <div class="top-bar-left">
                                <div class="top-bar-text text-white"><a href="#" class="font-medium display-inline">Now Hiring:</a> Are you a driven and motivated 1st Line IT Support Engineer?</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="top-bar-right">
                                <ul class="top-bar-info">
                                    <li class="info-item">
                                        <a href="tel:01228899900" class="info-link text-white">
                                            <i class="info-icon fa fa-phone"></i>
                                            <span class="info-text"><strong>0122 8899900</strong></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="info-item text-white">
                                        <i class="info-icon fa fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                                        <span class="info-text">58 Howard Street #2 San Francisco</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';}

    ?>
```

Comment: Are you really passing in the file name or do you need in to use basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])

Comment: @JasonK, better put it as an answer

Comment: @JasonK would of been good to use the filename but think I have just found a way to do it and seems to work. I'll edit my original post to include the code I have used